# Properly Mocking a CakePHP Controller's referer()

Tags: cakephp

I'm playing with CakePHP, building a simple blog site that just has posts and comments. I baked the models, controllers, and views. When you're viewing a post, it has a "Related Comments" section at the bottom, showing all of that post's comments. Each comment has action buttons ("View", "Edit", and "Delete"). I noticed that if you edit or delete a comment, you are *not* taken back to the post that you were viewing. Instead, you are taken to the comments index. The same thing happens when you're viewing a post and click the "New Comment" button at the bottom and add a new comment for that post. I wanted to modify this behavior so that if you're viewing a post and you edit or delete an existing comment or you add a new comment, you're redirected back to the post. I added code to each of these three actions ("add", "edit", and "delete") in the `Comments` controller. This question focuses on the "delete" action. This is what I did:

## Original Code in `app/Controller/CommentsController.php`

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Comment->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
    }
    $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
    if ($this->Comment->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

## Modified Code in `app/Controller/CommentsController.php`

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    /*
     * Same as above minus the redirect line (the following code replaces
     * the redirect line).
     */
    // Redirect to `$this->referer()` unless `$this->referer()`
    // is this comment's "edit" or "view" action (we do not want to
    // redirect the user to a 404 page), in which case redirect them
    // to the comments index.

    $referer = $this->referer();

    if ($referer) {
        $comingFromEditPage =
            mb_strpos(
                $referer,
                Router::url(array('action' => 'edit', $id), true)
            ) === 0;

        if (!$comingFromEditPage) {
            $comingFromViewPage =
                mb_strpos(
                    $referer,
                    Router::url(array('action' => 'view', $id), true)
                ) === 0;
        }

        if (!$comingFromEditPage && !$comingFromViewPage) {
            $redirectUrl = $referer;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $redirectUrl = array('action' => 'index');
    }

    return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
}
```

I wanted to test this behavior in my `app/Test/Case/Controller/CommentsControllerTest.php` file, so I made it look like this:

## CommentsControllerTest.php

```
<?php
App::uses('CommentsController', 'Controller');

class CommentsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array(
        'app.comment',
        'app.post'
    );

    public function tearDown() {
        parent::tearDown();
        unset($this->Controller);
    }

    public function testDeleteReferer() {
        // When the referer is the comment's "edit" action, deleting the
        // comment should redirect to the comments index.

        $this->Controller = $this->generate('Comments', array(
            'methods' => array(
                'referer'
            )
        ));

        $this->Controller->expects($this->any())->method('referer')->will(
            $this->returnValue(
                Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl') .
                $this->Controller->request->base .
                Router::url(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'comments',
                        'action' => 'edit',
                        '1',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $commentsIndexUrl =
            Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl') .
            $this->Controller->request->base .
            Router::url(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'comments',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            );

        $this->testAction(
            '/comments/delete/1',
            array('method' => 'post')
        );

        $this->assertEqual(
            $this->headers['Location'],
            $commentsIndexUrl
        );

        // When the referer is the comment's "view" action, deleting the
        // comment should redirect to the comments index.

        $this->Controller = $this->generate('Comments', array(
            'methods' => array(
                'referer'
            )
        ));

        $this->Controller->expects($this->any())->method('referer')->will(
            $this->returnValue(
                Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl') .
                $this->Controller->request->base .
                Router::url(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'comments',
                        'action' => 'view',
                        '2',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $this->testAction(
            '/comments/delete/2',
            array('method' => 'post')
        );

        // The following assertion fails on the command line!

        $this->assertEqual(
            $this->headers['Location'],
            $commentsIndexUrl
        );
    }

}
```

As stated in the code above, the second `assertEqual` fails on the command line. When I run `cake test --stderr app Controller/CommentsController`, this is the output:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 18.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) CommentsControllerTest::testDeleteReferer
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/comments'
+'http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/comments/view/2'

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php:552
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/app/Test/Case/Controller/CommentsControllerTest.php:93
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php:82
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestRunner.php:60
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/Command/TestShell.php:274
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/Command/TestShell.php:259
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php:440
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:207
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogtest/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:66

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Any idea why this happens on the command line even though the test works fine in the browser? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't understand why you go through all this trouble. It's quite simple to just redirect back to the referrer if your delete fails or to ``index`` if it succeeds. A simple if/else would have been enough. Also splitting if conditions in multiple lines makes it very hard to read the code. If you really need to get help, please follow conventions.

Comment: @user221931 Why do you think my goal is to redirect back to the referrer if the delete fails or to `index` if it succeeds? Personally, I think the formatting I used for the `if` statement is easier to read than this: `if ($this->referer() && !(mb_strpos($this->referer(), Router::url(array('action' => 'edit', $id), true)) === 0) && !(mb_strpos($this->referer(), Router::url(array('action' => 'view', $id), true)) === 0)) {`. Do you disagree? Also, what conventions am I not following, and how is that making it harder to get help?

Comment: So what is your goal then? Instead of confronting me with such attitude you can read up what is the expected coding standard for cakephp and _perhaps_ reflect on why you don't get any answers.

Comment: @user221931 My goal is shown in the comment at the top of the "delete" action in the "Modified Code in `app/Controller/CommentsController.php`" section. Confronting you with such attitude? What did I say that was rude? Also, I ran my code through [CakePHP Code Sniffer](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer) and it was fine other than my tests don't have function doc comments yet. So I'm still not sure what you're referring to. Lastly, you seem to be implying that the way my code is formatted has something to do with not having answers. Am I interpreting your comment correctly?

Comment: I took your reply as aggressive, my apologies. This is the product of written communication between strangers. You have `...` in your code so I don't know exactly what you do, but I expect you delete the comment. It makes no sense otherwise to not want to redirect to a 404 unless the comment was deleted. So your approach seems strange and can be solved/tested easier if you take my advice. Also it is bad practice to break down ``if`` statements. If it gets too complicated and can't do it otherwise use temp variables. Code that is too hard to read means less people bother with it.

Comment: @user221931 No worries. Yes, the `...` portion of the code deletes the comment. It's just standard `cake bake` code, so I didn't think I needed to include it. Do you think my if statement should be `if ($comingFromEditPage || $comingFromViewPage) {` instead of what I have now? Also, I think I'm missing something when you said "So your approach seems strange and can be solved/tested easier if you take my advice.". What seems strange about my approach and what advice are you suggesting I follow?

Comment: Yes, your example of ``if`` is now straightforward and fits in one line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your exact question but I believe solves your problem faster, cleaner and makes it much easier to understand and test.

You want to redirect to index if the delete succeeds (so as to not cause a 404) or to referrer if it fails.

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    if ($this->Comment->delete($id)) { //If comment deletion succeeds
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'); //Redirect to index
    } 
    return $this->redirect($this->referer()); //Else redirect to referrer
}
```

Notice how the `return` will stop further execution so you actually don't need an `else`. This code is now just 3 straightforward lines and only one indentation level deep.

Also I think this code hardly needs any testing since it is based on heavily tested core functionality. You can trust that `Model::delete()` or `Controller::redirect()` do their job and if you trust those you can trust that the controller method will perform as intended too. I think it is more important to test models than controllers (not meaning that controllers should be left out but I only bother to test things that are complicated or prone to changes/errors).

So if you still need to go to the testing extremes you can set `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to whatever you like (which will be picked up by `CakeRequest` as `$this->referer()`) and see if it is the url you are redirected to after a delete fails.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but actually what I'm trying to do is only a slight modification of the standard `delete` action that gets generated by `cake bake`. The action always redirects to `array('action' => 'index')`, regardless of if the delete was successful. All I want to do is change the redirect location from `array('action' => 'index')` to `$this->referer()`, but only if `$this->referer()` is *not* the comment's edit page or view page. It might seem weird to want to test that functionality, but I still want to, even just to satisfy my curiosity of what's wrong with my test code.

Comment: Can you include the full cake bake code? Just baked a test controller and got code almost identical to what I wrote before.

Comment: Yep, confirmed recent versions bake code like this. But think of it not as code you shouldn't touch, it as a template for most simple cases and you're supposed to extend to your needs. After all I'm not sure I'd classify your code as slight modification - though I would mine :) So I think enough is said good luck with it.

Comment: I don't think of `cake bake` code as code you shouldn't touch. My change isn't really small in terms of amount of code; it's small in terms of describing it. "Rather than *always* redirecting to the comments index, it only redirects there if the referer is the comment's edit or view page, otherwise it redirects to the referer". I awarded you the bounty because you gave me a fix (setting `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`). I also decided to mark this as correct since it tells me how to fix the problem, although it doesn't explain why the problem was happening.

Comment: What if in the future you add another method that you don't want to redirect back? Will you remember to revisit your code and manually add yet another string comparison and one more test? What if you change the route and ``edit`` is called something else in the url? This is why I said I don't think your code is a "small" modification, plus it does hardcoded string comparisons everytime it runs. Thanks for the bounty although that was not my goal, I do believe that if you let go of your initial thought and revisit the problem, this approach is "_better_" by all means.